Is it possible to make collection view resize itself in stack view in Swift
I have a horizontal collection view that I embedded in vertical stack view, how can I make collection view's height to fit its content. The code I have now:
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: Cell.self), for: indexPath) as? Cell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
        return cell
    }
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    private lazy var stack = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
        stack.distribution = .fill
        stack.alignment = .fill
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 4
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stack
    }()
    
    let contentView = UIView()
    
    let label = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.numberOfLines = 0
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.text = "Example 1"
        return l
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { index, _ in
            switch index {
            case 0:
                let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)))
                item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 4, bottom: 0, trailing: 4)
                let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.95), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)), subitem: item, count: 1)
                let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
                section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
                section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
                return section
            default:
                let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)))
                let verticalGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(200), heightDimension: .absolute(200)), subitem: item, count: 2)
                let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: verticalGroup)
                return section
            }
        }
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: Cell.self))
        stack.addArrangedSubview(collectionView)
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(contentView)
        stack.backgroundColor = .red
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .blue
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 1).isActive = true
        view.addSubview(stack)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.topAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let label = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.numberOfLines = 0
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.text = "Example 2"
        return l
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}


I already tried to set compression resistance but it didn't help. No matter what the height of a collection view remains 1, although there is clearly a space to expand.
